# returning sql connection sql lite

Tags: java, sql, methods, return

Button -> conectaDB(Connect DB) -> inseredadosBD(Insert data into db)

how can i return the connection to the inseredadosBD, to insert from the method?

Button event:

```
public void inseredadosBD(String grupo, int protocolo, String dataentrada, String escrevente, String auxiliar, String datalimite) {
    conectaBD();
-> here i will use the insert, i was planning to use something like conn.execute.. from here, but
}
```

i tryed         conectaBD(Connection conectado);,
 tryed      conectaBD(conectado);

to do something like conectado.execute.., but dont worked :/

Method conectaBD

```
public class metodos {
    public Connection conectado;
    public Connection conn;
    public Connection conectaBD() {
        //metodo responsavel por fazer a conexão com o BD
        try {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:c:\\grupo1.db");
//      Statement stm = conn.createStatement();  

        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Conectou" );
//          fechaconexaoBD(conn);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Conexão Fail");
        }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de conexão " );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return conn;
    }

..here go the rest of the code...
```

forget the //, i was just trying/testing things :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to include the error you are getting.

> i tryed conectaBD(Connection conectado);, tryed conectaBD(conectado);

These will not work as you have no method `conectaBD` defined to take a `Connection` as an argument.

**Edit** As per your comment,

> yes i have method conectaBD... its in the first code block !! isnt it a method because the "Connection"?? the problem is this, how can i pass the connection to the inseredadosBD, this is my question :

yes you do have the method `conectaBD()` but you are trying to call a method `conectaBD(Connection)` which you have not defined

But I can suggest several options:

1. Put your `inseredadosBD()` method within your `metodos` class, so you have access to your `Connection` variables. So then after calling `conectaBD` you would want to use `conn` as your connection
2. Pass the connection as an argument to your `inseredadosBD()` method then use that connection. Like `inseredadosBD(String.... , Connection c)` 
   **Edit** if you do this then you do not call `conectaBD()` inside this method, call it before calling this method and then call this method like this `inseredadosBD(/*data you want to insert*/, conn)` then in this method your `Connection` is called `c`, so you can use the conneciton Object c like below

   ```
   public void inseredadosBD(String grupo, int protocolo, String dataentrada, String escrevente, String auxiliar, String datalimite, Connection c) {
       c.//What ever connection method you want to use
         //here i will use the insert, i was planning to use something like conn.execute.
    }
   ```
3. Instantiate your `metodos` class within your... not very pretty tho

Comment: yes i have method conectaBD...  its in the first code block !! isnt it a method because the "Connection"??

the problem is this, how can i pass the connection to the inseredadosBD, this is my question :S

Comment: See edit to number 2, like that. Then pass connection in when you call inseredadosBD... just like any other Object in java

Comment: i tryed adding return conn; | and than adding conectaDB(conectado);... but return that its not applicable to this arguments (Connection)

Comment: I've edited again (for the final time). If you cannot understand what I'm telling you then I'm sorry but you need to learn to understand the basics of Java programming better

Comment: yes i understood now... but i made a global variable, out of the conectaBD

Connection conn = null;

so i can access if anywhere in the class, thank the answer